# What's the difference between logical (Leibniz) equality and local definition in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am having trouble understanding the difference between an equality and a local definition. For example, when reading the documentation about the `set` tactic:

> remember term as ident
>
> This behaves as set ( ident := term ) in * and
>   **using a logical (Leibniz’s) equality instead of a local definition**

Indeed,

1. `set (ca := c + a) in *.` e.g. generates `ca := c + a : Z` in the context, while
2. `remember (c + a ) as ca.` generates `Heqca : ca = c + a` in the context.

In case 2. I can make use of the generated hypothesis like `rewrite Heqca.`, while in case 1., I cannot use `rewrite ca`.

What's the purpose of case 1. and how is it different from case 2. in terms of practical usage?

Also, if the difference between the two is fundamental, why is `remember` described as a variant of `set` in the documentation (8.5p1)?

Answer (score 2):

You could think of `set a := b + b in H` as rewriting `H` to be:

```
(fun a => H[b+b/a]) (b+b)
```

or

```
let a := b + b in
H[b+b/a]
```

That is, it replaces all matched patterns `b+b` by a fresh variable `a`, which is then instantiated to the value of the pattern. In this regard, both `H` and the rewrited hypotheses remain equal by "conversion".

Indeed, remember is in a sense a variant of set, however its implications are very different. In this case, remember will introduce a new proof of equality `eq_refl: b + b = b + b`, then it will abstract away the left part. This is convenient for having enough freedom in pattern matching etc... This is remember in terms of more atomic tactics:

```
Lemma U b c : b + b = c + c.
Proof.
assert (b + b = b + b). reflexivity.
revert H.
generalize (b+b) at 1 3.
intros n H.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ejgallego's answer.

Yes, you cannot `rewrite` a (local) definition, but you can `unfold` it:

```
set (ca := c + a) in *.    
unfold ca.
```

As for the differences in their practical use -- they are quite different. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37521348/2747511) by @eponier. It relies on the `remember` tactic so that induction works as we'd like to. But, if we replace `remember` with `set` it fails:

```
Inductive good : nat -> Prop :=
  | g1 : good 1
  | g3 : forall n, good n -> good (n * 3)
  | g5 : forall n, good n -> good (n + 5).

Require Import Omega.
```

The variant with `remember` works:

```
Goal ~ good 0.
  remember 0 as n.
  intro contra. induction contra; try omega.
  apply IHcontra; omega.
Qed.
```

and the variant with `set` doesn't (because we didn't introduce [any free variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514716/wellfounded-induction-in-coq/37515705#comment62624150_37521348) to work with):

```
Goal ~ good 0.
  set (n := 0). intro contra.
  induction contra; try omega.
  Fail apply IHcontra; omega.
Abort.
```